# PHP move_uploaded_file not working when uploading too many files

Tags: php, html, post, image-uploading

I have created a HTML form where the user has to enter some information about houses and upload some photos to create an advertisement for that house.
When the user sends the form (via `POST`) with just one or two photos, the script works fine and the photos are uploaded to the right place, but
when the user tries to send, for example, twelve photos, the script doesn't even enter inside the `if(isset($_POST['submit']))` block.
Here is just a part of my code because it is pretty extensive?

*[Stripped code as it is unrelated to the issue ([history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/43032546/revisions))]*

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Can you share the front-end code as well. It also depends on you are submitting the information through front-end as that could also be the cause of the slowness.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are reaching PHP limits. So either disallow so much data in one request or tune up your PHP and increase at least these:

```
; Maximum allowed size for uploaded files.
upload_max_filesize = ...

; Must be greater than or equal to upload_max_filesize
post_max_size = ...
```

Comment: Sorry to just answer now. This solve my problem!! Thanks!!